# jQuery image resizing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, width, parsefloat

I've found this line of code somewhere using firebug and I know you need to put something where I've put the 3... behind parseFloat, but I have no idea what.
It works when I fill in a random number but the width is never the correct one and want to use it on several pages with photographs so it's always the correct size.

```
script type="text/javascript">
var badBrowser = (/MSIE ((5\.5)|6)/.test(navigator.userAgent) && navigator.platform == "Win32");
$(document).ready(function(){
var scaledwidth = ((parseFloat(...)*($(window).height()/4000))+50).toFixed(0);
if (badBrowser) {
$('#container img').css('height',$(window).height()+'px');
}
$('#container').css('width',scaledwidth+'px');
imageresize();
});
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
var scaledwidth = ((parseFloat(...)*($(window).height()/4000))+50).toFixed(0);
if (badBrowser) {
$('#container img').css('height',$(window).height()+'px');
}
$('#container').css('width',scaledwidth+'px');
imageresize();
});
function imageresize() {
var height = $(window).height();
if ((height) > 1340){
var quality='1440';
} else if((height) > 980) {
var quality='1080';
} else if((height) > 680) {
var quality='720';
} else if((height) > 480) {
var quality='640';
} else {
var quality='320';
}

}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would the correct size be? Or what characteristics should the correct size have? Because with the little information you've provided we can only guess. I'm guessing 42. btw do you expect `imageresize()` to do anything? Cause at the moment it just sets a variable that's never used.

Comment: Thx for the response, been out of town during the holidays.
The correct size would be whatever size the browser window is, so it would have to change together with the images when changing browser size. Here is where I got the code: http://jasperleonard.be/index.php?categorie=documentary&subcategorie=corporate&quality=720

@towr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the value you need to put there depends on the sum of the widths of all the images; so you can't just pick a value that works for all pages.

On the other hand, it also seems like a bad solution to the problem of keeping the images next to each other. Why set the width of the container? If you just ensure white-space doesn't wrap then all the images should sit next to each other without worrying about the container's width.

```
#container
{
    white-space: nowrap; /* keep images on the same line */
    font-size: 0;        /* removes whitespace between images */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8y4Z/

From the javascript, we now only need the `imageresize()` (provided we use it to set different quality source images), and trigger it on `ready` and `resize`; no magic numbers required.

(For backwards compatibility with browsers that don't or poorly support `white-space`, you could use `<nobr></nobr>`)

Comment: Only one thing that I would like to know and that's if I can add some space to the bottom? Padding or margin bottom doesn't seem to work on the img, top and left works fine.

Thanks again! @towr

Comment: `padding-bottom` on `img` works for me (in FF en Chrome), although the background from the container is cut off at the width of the window. Another option is to wrap each `img` with an div with `display:inline-block`, and style that how you want. If you have a jsfiddle or test-site I could probably give a better answer for what works in that specific case.

Comment: I guess the problem is I don't want a scrollbar on the side so I put overflow:hidden. If I remove this the padding works. So looking for a way to keep scroll hidden and have the padding.
Here's the link to the test site;
http://www.noortjepalmers.be/test2.html

Comment: You could put `bottom: 1cm` on `#container` so it'll leave 1cm of space at the bottom. But I think part of the problem is that the piece of javascript at the bottom gives each image window-height, but that's more than fits on the page, so the bottom gets cut off when you use `overflow:hidden` (including bottom padding). You could do without the javascript and let the container resize the images (though I've noticed they're not all equal height), or subtract about 60 or so from the window-height value before assigning the img-height.

Comment: SUPERB! With the subtraction it looks just the way I intended it, though I never thought I would get it to work. Can't thank you enough, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can i ask for one more question? I'm trying to put text underneath each photo but only seem to get it on the left or the right. any idea on who to do this? This is the CSS I'm using.


.image-container {
    color: #111111;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'webfontregular';
    font-size: 24px;
  }

Thanks in advance! @towr

Comment: @user2520747 Do you still have a test-page somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I already put the site online. This is the link to one of the pages with photo's: http://www.noortjepalmers.be/portraits.html

Comment: It should work if you wrap a div around the text (tested in firefox): `<div class=image-container><img ... /> <div>caption-text</div></div>`, the div is a block element so it goes to the next line (as long as you don't override it's display style).

Comment: Works great! Only thing is if I don't add a <div></div> or if I do and don't put anything in it the next img is suddenly a lot lower. But if I use <div></br></div> for the ones I don't want to add text to it works like a charm. Thanks once again!

Comment: Well, the works like a charm part seems to only be true when I try it offline, when I put it online it looks like this: http://www.noortjepalmers.be/advertisingbis.html. No idea why...

Comment: It seems to be missing the image-container style you mentioned before: `.image-container { color: #111111; display: inline-block; font-family: 'webfontregular'; font-size: 24px; }`

Comment: Ooops, shame on me. Uploaded the old .CSS. Sorry about that.